# Avoiding redundancy in parallel async tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am currently writing a small application with Node.js to help me with the edition and compilation of some custom file format. My problem is that I have lots async calls to read a directory, perform XHR requests or exec some child process, but must of these tasks should avoid being processed in parallel.

In example, I have a button to ask the content of a directory to the server : if I click quickly on this button it sends multiple times the same request and receives the same response as well. It would be better if once one request is fired, all the other identical requests "wait" for the common result.

I am using the [Async lib](https://github.com/caolan/async) and was trying to find a function to do it but I wasn't able to spot it. I also searched on Google & Stack Overflow but there was no satisfying answer - I do not really know how to "name" this problem.

In the past I used a solution of this form, but I feel there's certainly a better way :

```
var requesting = false ;
var callbacks = [] ;

var request = function ( target , cb ){
    callbacks.push(cb) ;
    if ( ! requesting ) {
        requesting = true ;
        asyncTask( target , function(err,resp){
            requesting = false ;
            for (var i=0,c=callbacks.length;i<c;i++) {
                callbacks[i](err,resp) ;
            }
        }) ;
    }
}


request( "/dirA" , function(err,resp){ ... } ) ;
request( "/dirA" , function(err,resp){ ... } ) ; //Ok, avoinding redundant code
request( "/dirB" , function(err,resp){ ... } ) ; //Problem -> You can use only one target
```

I'm searching for a general implementation, possibly allowing a lightweight use. Maybe something like :

```
var request = function ( target , cb ){
    avoidRedundancy( target , cb , function(){
        asyncTask( target , function(err,resp){
            //And now, how do I return the response ?
        }) ;
    }) ;
}
//avoidRedundancy( requestIdentifier , callback , taskToExecute )
```

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you just need a client-side response cache...

Comment: I cache what I can once I receive the answer, but it's not always possible. With a refresh button to get the content of the directory, the aim is to bypass the cache but no need to bypass it multiple times while the first request is not finished.

Comment: fair enough. you can still fix it client-side by disabling the  buttons while the ajax call is out. it can be done in node as well, but i fear that adds un-needed complication/restrictions to do correctly.

Comment: And here comes my question : how to correctly disable this button. (The button was just an easy example, the reason why I'm posting is especially because these quick async calls are executed by other code which I can't access)

Comment: you need a common-reachable boolean called isBusy.  you set isBusy=true when you make a request, and set it false upon response. in the part you make the requests, first ask if(!isBusy)... you can also update html attribs in those parts to button.diabled=true anything you are preventing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the Promise doc and greim's implementation but since I'm not that familiar with it (and not really sure about the event part "polluating" the main object), I found a simple solution to complete my last proposition :

```
var oneTaskCallbacks = {} ;
oneTask = function( reqId  , cb , task ){
    if ( !oneTaskCallbacks[reqId]) {
        oneTaskCallbacks[reqId] = [] ;
        oneTaskCallbacks.busy = false ;}
    var cur = oneTaskCallbacks[reqId] ;
    cur.push(cb) ;
    if (!cur.busy) {
        cur.busy = true ;
        task(function(err,rep){
            var cb ;
            for (var i=0;i<cur.length;i++) {
                cb = cur[i] ;
                cb && cb.apply(null,arguments) ;}
            cur.splice(0,cur.length);
            cur.busy=false ;
        }) ;
    }
}
```

It just asks a unique string to identify the task (ie. the ID of node to load), registers a callback and trigger the task with a single argument : a return callback to reply with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pattern using generic code that uses a promise to share a common result, like you're asking.

```
var promise;

emitter.on('thing', function(){
  if (!promise){
    promise = doSomethingAsync();
    promise.then(function(){
      promise = undefined;
    });
  }
  promise.then(function(result){
    // do something with result
  });
});
```

This works because the result of a promise can be accessed via `then` as many times as you want. If the "thing" happens again while the async call is still waiting, then `promise` will exist and and you don't need to create it. Otherwise, create a new one that removes itself once the task completes.

Comment: Thanks, I could improve my previous code but was still looking for a better one. I never really tried promises so I will read the MDN and try your answer.